# How to fix black screen after boot

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

After fresh installation Ubuntu 12.04 (with Wubi) everything runs good. Some updates were installed and after restart I saw the purple splash screen. Then I got a black screen. I tried `nomodeset` but that did not work.
I folow this instructions [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/137767/64192). I have Packard Bell EasyNote TK36 with motherboard model SJV52_MV V1.06 . Graphic is Intel GMA 4500MHD

Comment: How did you try `nomodeset`? What technique did you use, or what instructions did you follow? Also, please tell us the make and model of your computer (or if that doesn't apply, than of your motherboard), and the make and model of your graphics card. The best way for you to provide all this information is for you to edit your question to include it.